# GitHub enterprise customize the frontend

Tags: github, customization, enterprise

I have an enterprise setup of GitHub and I want to be able to customize the look and feel of my company's repositories.

Am I able to customize the frontend styles, add company logo, theme, etc?

Comment: This could be possible but it should take a lot of time.